# Qual é a saída dos plugins wysiwyg como Summernote e TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript

Alguém saberia me informar qual é a saída deste editores tipo **Summernote, TinyMCE, Froala, CKEditor4**. Olhei a documentação de todos estes e não entendi por exemplo como salvar o conteúdo em um banco de dados por exemplo, não sei o que gera, se é um Html, Json, texto?

```
<h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
</form>
```

---

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#mytextarea'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: É texto puro. Você pode salvar como longtext em um banco.

Comment: Com o CHEditor você pode levar tanto o texto puro sem tags HTML e/ou texto texto com formatação. A documentação é bem rica. https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/index.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda galera.